# Single separator line in a grouped bar chart (pgfplots)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

**Context:**

Two groups (sample A / sample B) were asked to express their opinion in six categories.

However, some people did not give an answer. Hence, I am trying to integrate this information in my grouped bar chart (amount of 
missing information).

**Question:**

I considered integrating a single separator line between F and "missing, but I did not find out how to do so.

Do you have a solution or other suggestions for a more reasonable solution?

***Optional design related question:***

Would you add the whole 100% scaling at y-axis (cf. MWE) or is this somehow a redundant information for you?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
compat=newest,
ybar = 0.6,
width=1\textwidth,
height=0.4\textheight,
ymin=0,
ymax=100,
enlarge x limits = 0.1,
x axis line style={opacity=1},
bar width=20pt,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=0},
ylabel={[\%]},
symbolic x coords={A, B, C, D, E, F, missing},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords,
axis lines*=left,
y axis line style={opacity=1},
cycle list={
    {fill=black!60,draw=black!60},
    {fill=black!40,draw=black!40},
    {fill=black!20,draw=black!20}
},
axis on top,
legend style={draw=none,/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}}
]

\addplot+[fill=black!10, text=black] coordinates {(A,62.5) (B,0) (C,4.5) (D,11.4) (E,14.8) (F,1.1) (missing,2.3)};
\addplot[fill=black!70,text=black] coordinates {(A,15.0) (B,0) (C,5.8) (D,43.7) (E,18.4) (F,17) (missing,0)};

\legend{sample X, sample Y}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nobody? Did I ask a wrong question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this you mean?

[image]

I added the dashed line with

```
\path (axis cs:F,0) -- coordinate (m) (axis cs:missing,0);
\draw [dashed] (m) -- (current axis.north -| m);
```

For the optional question, I think I'd be fine with either option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
compat=newest,
ybar = 0.6,
width=1\textwidth,
height=0.4\textheight,
ymin=0,
ymax=100,
enlarge x limits = 0.1,
x axis line style={opacity=1},
bar width=20pt,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=0},
ylabel={[\%]},
symbolic x coords={A, B, C, D, E, F, missing},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords,
axis lines*=left,
y axis line style={opacity=1},
cycle list={
    {fill=black!60,draw=black!60},
    {fill=black!40,draw=black!40},
    {fill=black!20,draw=black!20}
},
axis on top,
legend style={draw=none,/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}}
]

\addplot+[fill=black!10, text=black] coordinates {(A,62.5) (B,0) (C,4.5) (D,11.4) (E,14.8) (F,1.1) (missing,2.3)};
\addplot[fill=black!70,text=black] coordinates {(A,15.0) (B,0) (C,5.8) (D,43.7) (E,18.4) (F,17) (missing,0)};

\legend{sample X, sample Y}

\path (axis cs:F,0) -- coordinate (m) (axis cs:missing,0);
\draw [dashed] (m) -- (current axis.north -| m);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Pretty decent solution! :-)